# sed-style "-i[ext]" option parsing in Python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

In Python, how can I (without reinventing the `argparse` wheel) support a command-line option syntax à la `sed -i` in which one option takes an optional argument *if & only if* there is no whitespace between the option and its argument?

Naïvely, I'd expect `argparse` to support this by setting `nargs='?'`, like so:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-i', dest='backup', nargs='?', const='')
>>> parser.add_argument('arg', nargs='*')
```

... but it doesn't:

```
>>> parser.parse_args(['-i', '~'])
Namespace(backup='~', arg=[])  # wanted: Namespace(backup='', arg=['~'])
```

What options are available to me?  I'd prefer answers that work in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3+.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty workaround here.

First, manually check the `sys.argv[1:]` and check if the option (with `nargs='?', const=''`) is used with no optional argument (including `-o posarg` case that we are trying to resolve here).

If that so, modify that in a way to prevent it from consuming the trailing positional arguments, by appending `=` at the end of it.

Then explicitly give the modified args to the `parser.parse_args(argv)` function.

Following is the example script:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', dest='backup', nargs='?', const='')
parser.add_argument('arg', nargs='*')

print(parser.parse_args(['-i', '~']))  # gives Namespace(arg=[], backup='~')
print(parser.parse_args(['-i=', '~'])) # gives Namespace(arg=['~'], backup='')
```